# NgTable : how to clear filters

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using ngTable with filters.
How can I clear the filters values by clicking on one button?
I thought that `$scope.tableParams.reload();` would reset the filters but apparently it's not the case.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Like so: `$scope.tableParams.filter({});`

Answer (score 4):

You can clear the filters supplying an empty object (`{}`) to the `filter()` method of `tableParams` instance.
Look below inside the `ng-click` directives:

---

**If you are using controller as syntax:**

In controller:

```
this.tableParams = new NgTableParams(tableSettings, tableParams);
```

In view:

```
<div ng-controller="demoCtrl as demo">
  <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
          ng-disabled="!demo.tableParams.hasFilter()"
          ng-click="demo.tableParams.filter({})">
    Clear filters
  </button>
</div>
```

---

**If you are using controller with $scope syntax:**

In controller:

```
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams(tableSettings, tableParams);
```

In view:

```
<div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
  <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
          ng-disabled="!tableParams.hasFilter()"
          ng-click="tableParams.filter({})">
    Clear filters
  </button>
</div>
```